# How to display message or alert before update/ installing an app

Tags: android, installation, android-alertdialog, android-toast

[image]

As my question says, how to perform the following message or to edit it?
When a user updates it's app I want to prevent him that all the **data is lost** not as the current message tells. Thanks!

Comment: just launch intent for install apk .refer this link for install apk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The message in the snapshot that you've given is created by application installer so, I understand it as,

there might not be way to create that kind of message,

Instead if you have your application already installed you can create a message from your existing application whenever an update is triggered.

*I am not really positive that there is really no way to create a dialog like that., as there may be.*